# Dart - properly encode result from api

Tags: flutter, dart, utf-8

I am trying to solve the problem with chars encoding in api results. I have tried already to convince API provide to add utf-8 definition to header, but without success. So I need to convert result by myself in dart/flutter.

Tried already many things with Utf8Decoder or utf8.encode/decode, but without proper result.

Below example is in Polish. What I should have is:

*Czesi walczą z pożarem*

What I have in API results is:

*Czesi walczÄ z poÅ¼arem*

How can I decode the string to proper format?

Thanks!

Comment: Show the code which are using to make the HTTP call. There are multiple ways to do it so I want to make a solution that fits the way you are doing it.

Comment: I am doing this in FlutterFlow - and I need to build custom action (dart function) to decode these strings. What I get from API is JSON with strings I can process.

Comment: You need to have access to the raw bytes since you can then manually parse them using the charset of your choice. I don't know FlutterFlow and if that is even possible. But it is quite easy to do if you are writing the code.

Comment: I don't have access to raw bytes. I thought maybe I can decode string from API call to bytes, and then encode to proper string.

Comment: Not really going to work since the parsing have already failed. So if you are converting this string into bytes and then parse this, it is going to be the same result or not going to work in all cases.

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'walczą z pożarem' .encode('utf-8') .decode('latin1')` returns `'walczÄ\x85 z poÅ¼arem'` Note the byte (unprintable character) `\x85`: U+0085 *Next Line (NEL)*.

Comment: Thanks for comments! It looks like I will have to find another way to get the result I want.